# Optimize an algorithm by removing a td everytime it matches

Tags: jquery, algorithm, performance, optimization

I have an algorithm that (in Jquery):

1. Receives a `List<string>`
2. Searches a table for a match
3. Does some action

However I have been told there is a way to do this algorithm and only search through td's that haven't been matched (or more likely don't search through ones that have). Or any other ideas for optimizing the algorithm.

```
if (!jQuery.isEmptyObject(data)) {
    $td = $('#Table td');
    $.each(data.StringList, function (index, val) {
        $td.each(function () {
            if ($(this).text() === val) {
                $(this).closest(".ClassA").addClass('ClassB')
                $(".ClassB").find(".ClassC").removeClass('ClassC').addClass('ClassD');

                // Maybe something like $(td).skip($(this))
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

Thanks, If you need any more info please ask.

Comment: Please provide a sample

Comment: Please see updated code @Akshay

Comment: sample of whatever u t trying to do so that I can execute and run some tests.

Comment: Please see updated code @Akshay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could remove the elements that you already found from the collection, but that would be just as costly as finding it in the first place, so there is hardly any gain to be made there.

You can map the elements on the text into an object, then you can easily look up an element from the text:

```
if (!jQuery.isEmptyObject(data)) {
  $td = $('#Table td');
  var map = {};
  $td.each(function () {
    var t = $(this);
    map[t.text()] = t;
  });
  $.each(data.StringList, function (index, val) {
    if (val in map) {
      map[val].closest(".ClassA").addClass('ClassB');
      $(".ClassB").find(".ClassC").removeClass('ClassC').addClass('ClassD');
    }
  });
});
```

This will have an O(n+m) performance instead of O(n*m).

If the second line in the loop is trying to find the element that got the class `ClassB` in the first line, then you should just chain them together to use the reference to the element that you already have:

```
      map[val].closest(".ClassA").addClass('ClassB')
        .find(".ClassC").removeClass('ClassC').addClass('ClassD');
```

Comment: What an incredible piece of code cut waiting time from 15 s to 0.5 s, that a 3000% optimization, think that's worth a +1